# Maximal intersecting family of $X = \{1, \ldots, 7\}$

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

$X = \{1, \ldots, 7\}$. Give an example of an intersecting family $F$ of maximal size

Comment: Maybe consider for each $x \in X$ the set $A= X \setminus \{ x \}$

Comment: Without the constraint (that there is no element common to all the subsets) there are several maximal intersecting families.  For each $i\in X$ just take all the subsets containing $i$.  Not sure how the extra constraint plays out...I suggest working it out for smaller collections first.  Maybe there's a simple pattern.

Comment: It looks like the maximum is $2^{n-1}$ for $X=\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reasonable try is to take all subsets of size $4$ or greater.  Any pair must have nonempty intersection, and we have at least one subset not containing each element of the base set.  No set can be added, because a set of size $3$ or less has its complement in the family already and they have empty intersection.  This has size $1+7+21+35=64$.  To show it is maximal, I would try assuming a set of size $3$, say $\{1,2,3\}$ is in the family and show you can't get a family as large.

Rob Pratt's comment below shows this is maximal because no family can include both a set and its complement, so the maximum size is half the subsets.  We have achieved that.

Comment: Just from the intersecting constraint, we get an upper bound of $2^{n-1}$ because you can select at most one from each pair $(A, X \setminus A)$.