# Cardinality of the subsets

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Let $S$ be a collection of subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,100\}$ such that the intersection of any two sets in $S$ is non empty.

What is the maximum possible cardinality $|S|$ of set $S$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?  Have you produced some big collection that works?  Can you show an upper bound on the size of a good collection?  Anything?

Comment: Hint: if you take more than half the subsets, you must take a subset and its complement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximal intersecting family of $X = \{1, \ldots, 7\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3683484/maximal-intersecting-family-of-x-1-ldots-7)

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, right, I mixed up parities... I am deleting the comments to avoid confusion. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to get to $2^{99}$ sets by taking the set of all subsets containing 1.

It's not possible to get to any more than $2^{99}$ sets because if we did, we'd have a set and its complement both in $S$.

Comment: Not leaving much for OP to do.

Answer (score 0):

As $\{1,2,...,100\}$ is a finite set, then we can say that all sets in $S$ has a common element. Let $1$ be the common element. Then each other element can either be in or not be in a given subset. So using basic combinatorics, the total number of possible subsets with $1$ as one of its elements is $2^{99}$, as there are 99 other elements to choose from. So that's your answer. Total of $2^{99}$ sets in collection $S$.

Sorry for bad formatting by the way.

Comment: Provide more details please.

Comment: This shows that it’s possible to get at least $2^{99}$ subsets, no two of which are disjoint, but it does not show that this is the maximum possible. For that see **Gerry Myerson**’s comment above.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott sir ,please provide a helpful answer . I do wanna know more about it with some more details.

Comment: @Alearner the way to be a learner is to work out the details yourself. You have been given more than enough information to do that, and no one should deprive you of the joy that comes from filling in the blanks on your own.

Comment: I'm afraid we cannot say that all sets in $S$ have a common element. Take $S = \{\{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{2, 3\}\}$. Then the intersection of any 2 elements of $S$ has a common element, but not the intersection of all three.

Comment: @Doctor, true, but there's a bigger qualifying set of subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$ than that. Perhaps $\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$ would be a better illustration of the point.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Good example.